# Projective objects in the category of finite groups

Tags: category-theory, finite-groups

It's clear $1$ is a projective object in the category of finite groups. Are there any others?

Note that the dual problem, for injective objects, is comparatively easy (using Cayley's theorem).

Comment: I don't know the answer yet, I'm thinking about it; I found that such a $P$ was non abelian, and then improved the result to prove that $P$ was perfect.

Comment: @Max Indeed, Suppose $P$ has a nontrivial abelian quotient. Then its ha a non-trivial cyclic quotient $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. But that surejction $P\to \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ cannot be lifted to $\Bbb Z/nm\Bbb Z$ for $m\gg 1$: some element of $P$ would have to be mapped to a generator.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : yup; I was trying some other things like using the Cayley embedding, but I don't know any nonsplit surjection $K\to \mathfrak{S}_n$; or I tried to see if there was any reason why we could find a finite quotient of the free group on $P$ generators that was larger than $P$ but no luck there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no others. Here's a proof using well-known facts about the cohomology of finite groups.

Let $G$ be a nontrivial finite group, and let $p$ be a prime dividing the order of $G$. Then there is a finite dimensional (and hence finite) $\mathbb{F}_pG$-module $M$ with $H^2(G,M)\neq0$. A nonzero cohomology class represents a non-split extension $1\to M\to\tilde{G}\to G\to1$.

If the existence of $M$ is not familiar, but you believe that $H^k(G,\mathbb{F}_p)\neq0$ for some $k>0$, then you can produce $M$ from the trivial $\mathbb{F}_pG$-module $\mathbb{F}_p$ by dimension shifting. Or for a specific $M$, take an exact sequence
$$0\to M\to P_1\to P_0\to\mathbb{F}_p\to0,$$
where $P_1\to P_0\to\mathbb{F}_p\to0$ is a projective presentation of the trivial $\mathbb{F}_pG$-module.

Comment: group cohomology question -- What if there is a splitting of the extension as abstract groups which is incompatible with the given action of $G$ on $M$?

Comment: @hunter I'm not sure what you mean by a splitting being compatible with the action on $M$. A splitting is simply a group homomorphism $G\to\tilde{G}$ such that the composition $G\to\tilde{G}\to G$ is the identity map. In any case, the action of $G$ on $M$ is determined by the map $\tilde{G}\to G$.

Comment: Yes, but @hunter is right in that $H^2(G,M)$ assumes a given action on $M$, and it classifies extensions $1\to M\to A\to G\to 1$ such that the induced action is the given one

Comment: @hunter : ah actually I just realized it doesn't make sense to ask that : a nontrivial cohomology class in $H^2(G,M)$ *provides* an extension $\tilde{G}$ that induces the action on $M$; and that isn't split. Sorry Jeremy for the mixup

Comment: @JeremyRickard yes now that I think about it this is just fine.

Comment: Jeremy, I do have some more questions : what happens in your dimension shifting argument if $k=1$ ? And why should we believe that $H^k(G,\mathbb{F}_p) \neq 0$ for some $k$ ?

Comment: @Max If $k=1$, choose a short exact sequence $0\to M\to P\to\mathbb{F}_p\to0$ with $P$ projective/injective and then $H^1(G,\mathbb{F}_p)\cong H^2(G,M)$. If you don't want to assume $H^k(G,\mathbb{F_p})\neq0$ for some $k>0$ then take a short exact sequence $0\to N\to\mathbb{F}_pG\to\mathbb{F}_p\to0$ and, checking that the induced map $H^0(G,\mathbb{F}_pG)\to H^0(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ is non-zero, deduce from the long exact sequence that $H^1(G,N)\neq0$, and then dimension shift using a short exact sequence $0\to M\to P\to N\to0$ to get $H^2(G,M)\neq0$.

Comment: @Max By the way, the fact that $H^0(G,\mathbb{F}_pG)\to H^0(G,\mathbb{F}_p)$ is nonzero requires that $p$ divides $|G|$. Also, for a finite group, injective and projective modules coincide for the group algebra over a field, so positive degree cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_pG$ (or any projective module) vanishes.

Comment: @Max Doh! In both my two previous comments, "nonzero" should be "zero".

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy ! (when thinking about the question of the OP I had actually seen the link with cohomology, but I didn't know enough to prove that the condition $H^2(G,-) = 0$ was too strong -though intuitively it seemed so)